# bittorrent prioritize torrents for uploading

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, rtorrent, ktorrent

There are certain torrents in my list which I'd like to prioritize when it comes to seeding.
Is there a torrent client which has this option?

I want to mention that hacks like pausing every other torrent or limiting the uploading limit of each other torrent is not a sustainable long term solution. 
Hacks that are sustainable, are of course welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In μTorrent you can right click on any torrent > `Bandwidth Allocation`. `High`/`Normal`/`Low` indicates relative priority.

It's also possible to set torrent-specific upload speed limits through this menu.

When a torrent is set to high priority, (almost) all bandwidth is taken from other torrents and given to it until it's satisfied, i.e. the people at the other end are downloading at their maximum speeds. When there are no other peers for high priority torrents, other torrents behave normally.

This setting applies to both downloading and seeding torrents.

There's some minor discussion on it [here](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=2620).

It's also possible to set priorities on individual files, but I'm not sure if that applies to seeding.

Comment: hmm I'm running ubuntu, will figure out how to install μTorrent on it hopefully

Comment: I've installed μTorrent on my ubuntu following the http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/install-utorrent-in-ubuntu-fedora/ guide

Answer (score 1):

This example of [dynamic throttle management](http://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/RtControlExamples#Bandwidth_Management) does it for rtorrent, you just have to adapt it to your use-case.

Comment: Hmm I'll have to be more awake to understand the code there, as I assume I must reverse it in order to use it. 

Then again it'll cause problems with torrents I want to seed but haven't got past 1:1 with yet won't it?

Comment: Why would it, the "Put torrents seeded above 1:1 into the seed throttle" job explicitely filters for complete and seeded back items.

Comment: hmm k, I think I'll stay away from learning the code anyhow xD